# how to calculate $E(|Z^\frac{4}{3}|)$

Tags: normal-distribution

As we all know, $E(|Z|)$ is $\sqrt(\frac{\pi}{2})$, where Z~N(0,1)

How to calculate $E(|Z^\frac{4}{3}|)$

Or someone can just tell me the value without the process, because typing Latex is so annoying.

Comment: The expected value of $N(0, 1)$ is $0$ by definition. Did you mean something else?

Comment: sorry I forgot the abs

Comment: The answer is given using the Gamma function : $E[|Z|^{\frac 43}] = \frac{2^{\frac 23}\Gamma\left(\frac 76\right)}{\sqrt \pi}$

Answer (score 2, accepted):

We can calculate more generally

$$\mathbb{E}(|Z|^r) = \sqrt{ \frac{2}{\pi} } \int_0^{\infty} x^r e^{- \frac{x^2}{2} } \, dx$$

as follows. Substituting $y = \frac{x^2}{2}, dx = \frac{dy}{x} = \frac{dy}{\sqrt{2y}}$ gives

$$\sqrt{ \frac{2}{\pi} }  \int_0^{\infty} (2y)^{\frac{r-1}{2}} e^{-y} \, dy = \boxed{ \frac{2^{\frac{r}{2}}}{\sqrt{\pi}} \Gamma \left( \frac{r+1}{2} \right) }.$$

Substituting $r = \frac{4}{3}$ gives

$$\mathbb{E} \left( |Z|^{\frac{4}{3}} \right) = \boxed{ \frac{2^{\frac{2}{3}}}{\sqrt{\pi}} \Gamma \left( \frac{7}{6} \right) \approx 0.831 \dots }$$

where $\Gamma \left( \frac{7}{6} \right) \approx 0.928 \dots$ does not appear to have a closed form.

Comment: Interesting : they write in the Wikipedia page for "special values of the gamma function" that $\Gamma(\frac 16)$ (and more generally $\Gamma(\frac{n}{24})$ for integer $n$) actually can be expressed algebraically in terms of $\pi$ (I think that means, that it can be written as a polynomial in $ \pi$ with rational coefficients).  Then $\Gamma(\frac 76) = \frac 16\Gamma(\frac 16)$. This is not useful, but just nice to know, I suppose.+1

Comment: thank you very much！

Answer (score 1):

> As we all know, $E(|Z|)$ is $\sqrt{\frac{\pi}{2}}$, where $Z\sim N(0,1)$

I do not know this fact....but calculating it I get

$$\mathbb{E}[|Z|]=\int_{-\infty}^{+\infty}|z|\phi(z)dz=\frac{1}{\sqrt{2\pi}}\Bigg\{e^{-z^2/2}\Big]_{-\infty}^0-\{e^{-z^2/2}\Big]_{0}^{+\infty}\Bigg\}=\sqrt{\frac{2}{\pi}}$$

Comment: Yes , it was a mistake, but I thought it was a typo.

Comment: yeah I think you are right